# not able to retrieve data from datastore GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have a Class User

```
class User(db.Model):
  userId = db.StringProperty()
  email = db.StringProperty()
  channelToken = db.StringProperty()
```

I inserted a record with

```
user = User(key_name='1',userId='1',email='abc@gmail.com',channelToken='123')
user.put()
```

It is perfectly inserted. But now when I am trying to retrieve it, it is showing an error

```
channelToken= db.GqlQuery("SELECT channelToken FROM User WHERE userId=1") 
logging.info("Found Channel : " + str(channelToken))
```

it is showing

```
<google.appengine.ext.db.GqlQuery object at 0xfe112370>" is not a string.
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: like the answer said, `get()` returns a single instance where `.fetch()` returns list of found instances.

Comment: if you know you user id is unique, then store the userid in the key_name, and then use get rather than perform a query, you will then not have to worry about eventual consistency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlqueryclass#GqlQuery

```
q = db.GqlQuery("SELECT channelToken FROM User WHERE userId=1") 
channelToken = q.get()
```

The logging was giving a memory location because GqlQuery returns an object.

Comment: thanks ! this is working. How can I delete the particular record ?

Comment: Refer the documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass#Model_delete

Answer (score 1):

You may use `gql` also.

```
channelToken = User.gql("WHERE userId = :1", "1").get().channelToken
```

To delete all the records which has  `userId = 1`

```
users = User.gql("WHERE userId = :1", "1").fetch()
for user in users:
    user.key.delete()
```